# irreducible over $\mathbb R[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A = \mathbb R[x,y]$ where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Show that $A$ is an integral domain.

My thoughts are to show that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is irreducible over  $\mathbb R[x,y] =  \mathbb R[x][y],$ I am guessing that I can use Einstein criterion, is that correct? if so how?

Could someone push me in the right direction please?

**EDIT:**

I also know that:

1-Irreducibles are primes in a UFD.

2-$\mathbb R[x], \mathbb R[y]$ are UFD because $R$ is a field. And $<x^2 + y^2 -1>$ is a prime ideal in $B[y]$(where B = R[x] and where $B[y]$ is a UFD) iff $<x^2 + y^2 -1>$ is irreducible in $B[y]$

3- $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Note that your ring $\mathbb R[x,y] = \mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$, and $X^2+Y^2-1$ is irreducible. Indeed, writing $X^2+(Y+1)(Y-1)$ we see that it is Eisenstein at the primes $Y+1$ and $Y-1$.

Comment: why my ring equal this ? do you have a proof for this? I for my life can not see it @Nico

Comment: @Nico how can I apply Eisenstein Criterion in my case?

Comment: The ring $R[x,y]$ with $x^2+y^2 = 1$ is by definition the ring in which $x^2+y^2-1 = 0$. In other words, you quotient out by the ideal $(x^2+y^2-1)$, thus any multiple of $(x^2+y^2-1)$ is zero. Can you see how we can interpret the ring $R[x_1,...x_n]$ such that $f_1(x_1,...,x_n) = \cdots = f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ as $R[X_1,...,X_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_m)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may as well make this an answer. The ring $A$ is simply $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ which is an integral domain because the ideal $(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is prime. It's prime because $\mathbb R[X,Y]$ is an integral domain, so an ideal $(f(X,Y))$ is prime iff $f(X,Y)$ is irreducible. Indeed, $X^2+Y^2-1 = X^2+(Y+1)(Y-1)$ which is Eisenstein at the primes $Y\pm 1$.

A very similar argument shows that the ring $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^n+Y^n-1)$ is an integral domain. If you've seen any algebraic geometry, this is the same as the fact that the Fermat curve $V(X^n+Y^n-1)$ is irreducible, i.e. an algebraic variety. This time, write $X^n+(Y-1)(1+Y+\cdots+Y^{n-1})$ which is still Eisenstein at $Y-1$.

Comment: but we can not say $\mathbb R[X,Y]$ is an integral domain .... this is actually what we want to prove .... am I correct?

Comment: It is not very clear to me how we applies Eisenstein criterion ... could you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: The ring $\mathbb R[X,Y]$ is the polynomial ring in two variables over $\mathbb R$ which is an integral domain. By Gauss' lemma, $\mathbb R[X,Y]$ is an integral domain. The ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$ is the quotient ring $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ where we set $x = X + I$ and $y = Y+I$ and $I = (X^2+Y^2-1)$. So the little $x$ and little $y$ are the images of $X$ and $Y$ in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$. Thus $x^2+y^2 - 1 = (X+I)^2+(Y+I)^2-1 = X^2+Y^2-1 + I = I$ which is zero in the ring $\mathbb R[X,Y]/I$ by definition of the quotient ring.

Comment: To apply Eisenstein, think of the ring $R[X,Y]$ as $R[Y][X]$ (i.e. polynomials in $X$ whose coefficients come from $R[Y]$). Then $X^2 + (Y+1)(Y-1) = X^2 + 0\cdot X^1 + (Y+1)(Y-1)\cdot X^0$. The constant term is divisible by $Y+1$ (which is irreducible) but not $(Y+1)^2$, the $X^1$-term has a factor of $Y+1$ (since 0 is trivially divisible by $Y+1$), and the leading term is 1.

Comment: Sorry if I am bothering you will a lot of questions and thanks for your patience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120096/discussion-between-nico-and-mathfear).

Comment: I think you meant that $R[X,Y]$ is a UFD ... am I correct? because in the UFD irreducibles are primes.

Comment: How can we prove that $Y + 1$ is irreducible here? we do not have a degree function so I can not tell any polynomial of degree 1 is irreducible ? I already know the determinant of the representation matrix of $A$ will that help you in the proof?

Comment: Here is the matrix of $A$: $$\phi:A \rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb R[x]), \phi (a_{1} + a_{2}y) =  \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2}(1-x^2) \\
a_{2} & a_{1} 
\end{pmatrix} $$